# Password verification using javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing password verification. I enter the password and then i re enter the password. But at every key press it gives me a tick mark sign which I dont want and also, even if I enter a wrong password it doesn't go the else part which gives the delete image. Can someone help me out. I am new at this.

```
function checkPasswordMatch() {
var password = $("#password").val();
var confirmPassword = $("#verifyPassword").val();

if (password != confirmPassword)
{
    $("#marker").prepend('<img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/freeapplication/png/24x24/Apply.png" />');
}

else
{
    $("#marker").prepend('<img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/musthave/16/Delete.png" />');
}
```

}

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#verifyPassword").keyup(checkPasswordMatch);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 problems with your approach.

First, to prevent the function to run at every keypress use the `change` event instead of `keyup`.

Second, I think you inverted the statement in the if, use `==` instead of `!=`

```
function checkPasswordMatch() {
  var password = $("#password").val();
  var confirmPassword = $("#verifyPassword").val();
  if (password == confirmPassword){
    $("#marker").html('<img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/freeapplication/png/24x24/Apply.png" />');
  }else{
    $("#marker").html('<img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/musthave/16/Delete.png" />');
  }
}
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(document).on('keyup','#verifyPassword', checkPasswordMatch );
});
```

---

edit: changed back the `keyup` event to match the request

Comment: @Luca....thank you..that worked.. Only one question. can I show the tick mark or the delete when i am typing the password. Right now, what it does is, when i am finished typing the password and click somwhere else it gives the image

Comment: If you want the image at every keypress then use `keyup` instead of `change` in the JQuery event binding. Tought you didn't want the image at every keypress.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent this of happening each time you type somthing, you should change your event. I advise you to use the `change` event, at the passwords fields. See:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('change','#password, #verifyPassword', checkPasswordMatch );
});
```

Comment: when i click on the verify password text box, it gives me a tick sign and also it does not give me delete image which i gave in else part when i enter wrong password